# Flatten inner array but assign outer properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, lambda, flatten

I have an input like this:

```
var input = [
    {
        "inner_array": [
            {
                "inner_data": "inner_data1"
            },
            {
                "inner_data": "inner_data2"
            }
        ],
        "outer_data": "outer_data",
    }
];
```

And I'd like to process it so it becomes this.

```
var output = [
    {
        "inner_data": "inner_data1",
        "outer_data": "outer_data",
    },
    {
        "inner_data": "inner_data2",
        "outer_data": "outer_data",
    }
];
```

In words: I'd like to flatten an inner array, while still keeping the outer array's properties. Does this have an easy solution (with built in lambda array functions), or should I write a function myself which handles this?

Comment: what, if you have more than one property with an array inside?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: @Andy This is obviously not the code I'm actually running. This is a simplified example that hopefully makes the problem easy to understand. I'm not sure what you're asking of me.

Comment: The point of SO is not to write code for you but to help you with code that you've already written that you may be having problems with. We're not a code-writing service. You really need to show that you've put some effort into trying to solve the problem yourself. @botiapa

Comment: @Andy That's fair, altough in this case I disagree. There would've been no point in copying the code that I've written, since it's obviously wrong. I just wanted to get an idea of how to proceed. I tried using flatMap, but I haven't realized that I could chain a flatMap and a Map together. In my opinion it was better to provide a clear example, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on your `input` array to loop over each object, along with an inner [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each inner_array to a new object. The new object can be a combination of the `outer_data` value along with the `inner_data` value. The `.flatMap()` method will then merge all returned objects from the inner `.map()` calls for each object within `input` into one resulting array:

```js
const input = [{ "inner_array": [{ "inner_data": "inner_data1" }, { "inner_data": "inner_data2" } ], "outer_data": "outer_data", }];

const res = input.flatMap(obj => obj.inner_array.map(inner => ({
  ...inner,
  outer_data: obj.outer_data
})));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the combining flatMap and map functions is a great and elegant solution.